# changing two columns to one column based on another columns

Tags: r

i have two data frames named df and df1. in df1 "prob-districts" are divided into two columns. i want to merge df with df1 based on gender and district to finally have on column of prob-district. thank you in advance.

```
df1 <- structure(list(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), district = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), gender = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df <- structure(list(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), gender = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1), district1 = c(0.0099, 0.0021, 0.0029, 0.0037, 0.005), district2 = c(0.0124, 0.002, 0.0021, 0.0042, 0.0076)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can reshape the 'df1' data to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, extract the digits part from the column names, and do a `right_join` with the first data 'df'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = contains('district'), 
       names_to = 'district', values_to = 'prob') %>%
    mutate(district = as.integer(str_extract(district, "\\d+"))) %>%
    right_join(df, by = c('age', 'district', 'gender'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     age gender district    prob
   <int>  <int>    <int>   <dbl>
 1    10      1        1 0.0099 
 2    10      1        2 0.0124 
 3    11      2        1 0.0021 
 4    11      2        2 0.002  
 5    12      1        1 0.00290
 6    12      1        2 0.0021 
 7    13      2        1 0.0037 
 8    13      2        2 0.0042 
 9    14      1        1 0.005  
10    14      1        2 0.0076
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(age = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L), district = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), gender = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df1 <- structure(list(age = 10:14, gender = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), `prob-district(1)` = c(0.0099, 
0.0021, 0.0029, 0.0037, 0.005), `prob-district(2)` = c(0.0124, 
0.002, 0.0021, 0.0042, 0.0076)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: can you try now

Comment: I got this Error: Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `district`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
merge(
  df1,
  reshape(
    setNames(
      df,
      gsub("district", "prob.", names(df))
    ),
    direction = "long",
    idvar = c("age", "gender"),
    varying = -(1:2),
    timevar = "district"
  ),
  all.x = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
   age district gender   prob
1   10        1      1 0.0099
2   10        2      2     NA
3   11        1      2 0.0021
4   11        2      1     NA
5   12        1      1 0.0029
6   12        2      2     NA
7   13        1      2 0.0037
8   13        2      1     NA
9   14        1      1 0.0050
10  14        2      1 0.0076
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), district = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), gender = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df <- structure(list(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), gender = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1), district1 = c(0.0099, 0.0021, 0.0029, 0.0037, 0.005), district2 = c(0.0124, 0.002, 0.0021, 0.0042, 0.0076)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: no i want to have just one column of prob

Comment: thank you but the output should be equal to  the number of district and gender row.

Comment: @mehmo Thanks for your feedback. I fixed it.

Comment: i got this : Error in guess(varying) : 
  failed to guess time-varying variables from their names
>

Comment: @mehmo Could you `dput(df1)` to see how your data looks like?

Comment: it is like this:  structure(list(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
), district = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), gender = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: @mehmo put both `dput(df)` and `dput(df1)` in your post.

Comment: dput (df) : structure(list(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), gender = c(1, 2, 
1, 2, 1), district1 = c(0.0099, 0.0021, 0.0029, 0.0037, 0.005
), district2 = c(0.0124, 0.002, 0.0021, 0.0042, 0.0076)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: thank you ThomasIsCoding but why it contains "NA"?

Comment: @mehmo You have NA since you don't have matched values in columns "age", "gender", and "district"

Comment: ThomasIsCoding can you explain what exactly do argument "varying" in your cod?

Comment: @mehmo You can `?reshape` and see `varying` argument, which gives better and detailed  description than me :)